# Validating a form is not working in my page

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery mobile 1.4.3.

I am using `validate` function for my form validation.

But its not working. This is the first time I am using it. I am not getting where I went wrong.

please any body help me.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery("#registrarse").validate({

        errorClass: "msg_contacto",
        onkeyup: false,
        rules: {
            im_Nombre: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            im_Email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            im_cEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                equalTo: "#registrarse #im_Email"
            },
            im_Telefono: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            im_Nombre: {
                required: 'Campo Requerido',
                minlength: 'Su nombre debe tener al menos 3 caracteres'
            },
            im_Email: {
                required: 'Campo Requerido',
                email: 'E-mail inválido',
            },
            im_cEmail: {
                required: 'Campo Requerido',
                email: 'E-mail inválido',
                equalTo: 'Confirme correctamente su E-mail'
            },
            im_Telefono: {
                required: 'Campo Requerido'
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

            error.appendTo(element.nextAll("span.mensaje"));
        }

    });

});
```

Here is the link to jsfiddle: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsg5s/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[**Use this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Praveen16oct90/qsg5s/2/)

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {

$("#registrarse").validate({

    errorClass: "msg_contacto",
    onkeyup: false,
    rules: {
        im_Nombre: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        im_Email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        im_cEmail: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            equalTo: "#registrarse #im_Email"
        },
        im_Telefono: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        im_Nombre: {
            required: 'Campo Requerido',
            minlength: 'Su nombre debe tener al menos 3 caracteres'
        },
        im_Email: {
            required: 'Campo Requerido',
            email: 'E-mail inválido',
        },
        im_cEmail: {
            required: 'Campo Requerido',
            email: 'E-mail inválido',
            equalTo: 'Confirme correctamente su E-mail'
        },
        im_Telefono: {
            required: 'Campo Requerido'
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

        error.appendTo(element.nextAll("span.mensaje"));
    }

});

 });
```

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js

Use this plugin